# Can I copy an older version of a file from a previous commit using GitPython?

Tags: python, git, file, copy, gitpython

As part of a python script I am working on, I need to be able to make a local copy of a file from a previous commit in a Git Repository. Is there a way to do this using gitPython?

I saw in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48802091/how-to-get-file-data-from-a-specific-git-commit-using-gitpython#) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429482/gitpython-how-can-i-access-the-contents-of-a-file-in-a-commit-in-gitpython) that it's possible to copy the file data and write it to a new file. However, some of the files I need to copy will be zip-files, so it would be much more efficient to be able to copy the file with a direct path.